# How to Populate CartItem schema product details into Order Schema using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

**I want to populate the details of products in my order.** Currently it is only adding product id inside the products array. I tried a couple of methods but none seems to work.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const CartItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  product: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
  quantity: Number,
  shop: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Shop'},
  status: {type: String,
    default: 'Not processed',
    enum: ['Not processed' , 'Processing', 'Shipped', 'Delivered', 'Cancelled']}
})
const CartItem = mongoose.model('CartItem', CartItemSchema)
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  products: [CartItemSchema],
  customer_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Name is required'
  },
  customer_email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
    required: 'Email is required'
  },
  delivery_address: {
    street: {type: String, required: 'Street is required'},
    city: {type: String, required: 'City is required'},
    state: {type: String},
    zipcode: {type: String, required: 'Zip Code is required'},
    country: {type: String, required: 'Country is required'}
  },
  payment_id: {},
  updated: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
})

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema)

export {Order, CartItem}
```

I tried doing this:

```
const create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    req.body.order.user = req.profile;
    console.log(req);
    let order = new Order(req.body.order);

    let neworder = await Order.findById(order._id)
      .populate("products.product", "name price")
      .populate("products.shop", "name")
      .exec();
    // console.log(order);
    let result = await order.save();
    sendMail(order);

    res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err),
    });
  }
};
```

Also tried using this for poulating the product details but doesnt seem to work!

```
Order.findById(order._id).populate({ path: "products.product", select: "_id name price" })
```